# StackOverflowError - adding a value to a heap

Tags: java, algorithm, heap

I'm currently working on an applet that displays a heap as values are added and removed.  I'm implementing the heaps as tree of integers - IntTrees.  I'm writing the code for skew heaps, and the 'add' method is giving me some trouble. The add method usually works, but once in a while it causes a stack overflow error when a value is added, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's the code I have written for the add method

't' is an instance variable - the heap itself.

```
 // adds value to heap
 public void add(int value) {

IntTree smallTree = new IntTree(value, empty(), empty());

 if (t == null) {
  t = smallTree;
 } else {
  t = merge(t, smallTree);
  }
}

public IntTree merge(IntTree left, IntTree right) {

if (isEmpty(left)) return right;
if (isEmpty(right)) return left;

int leftVal = left.value();
int rightVal = right.value();
IntTree result;

if (rightVal <= leftVal) {
  result = merge(right,left);
} else {
  result = left;

  if (result.isEmpty(left)) {
    result.setLeft(right);
  } else {
    IntTree temp = result.right();
    result.setRight(result.left());
    result.setLeft(merge(temp,right));
  }
}

    return result;
  }
```

Is there something in this code that would cause a stack overflow error, or is the problem perhaps elsewhere in the program?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet

```
if (rightVal <= leftVal) {
  result = merge(right,left);
```

What happens when `rightVal == leftVal`?

Comment: Thanks.  That was a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

@Adam has found the problem for you.  This is to help you find problems like this yourself.

When you get an unexpected error or exception, it is important to study the stack trace carefully.  There is often *a lot of information* in a stack trace ... if you know how to read it.

In this case, you would have seen that there were many, many stack frames for the `merge` method.  If you had looked at them carefully, you would have noticed that `merge` was calling `merge` from the same line of code, over and over again.  This is a classic sign of a recursion loop.

Given those clues (and especially the line number at which the recursion was happening), it would have been a simple matter to figure out why you had a recursion loop.